# How to perform an automatic login after confirming the account with ASP.NET Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, email, asp.net-identity

I'm currently developing an MVC5 web app, using ASP.NET Identity 2 for account control, the specific problem I'm having concerns automatically logging in the user **after** e-mail confirmation.

So the flow is as follows:

1. User clicks on the Register link
2. Enters email (username) / password, hits Register
3. An email is sent to the given address with a "please confirmaccount" URL
4. User clicks the link, confirming email address and is automatically logged in

**The confirm email action on the controllers looks like this:**

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> ConfirmEmail(string userId, string code)
{
   // If userId or code is empty, show an error or redirect
   if (userId == null || code == null)
   {
     return View("Error");
   }

   // Attempt to confirm the email address
   var confirmEmailResult = await UserManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(userId, code);

   // Retrieve the user (ApplicationUser)
   var user = await UserManager.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == userId);
   if (user == null)
   {
     // If the user doesn't exist, redirect home
     return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
   }

   // If the confirmation succeeded, sign in the user and redirect to this profile page
   if (confirmEmailResult.Succeeded)
   {
     await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, false, false);

     var url = Url.Action("Profile", "User");
     return RedirectToLocal(url);
   }

   // In all other cases, redirect to an error page
   return View("Error");
}
```

The weird thing is, I can either confirm the e-mail *or* sign in the user, for some reason if I do both... it doesn't work. Specifically, I get a TimeOutException on this line:

```
await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, false, false);
```

which is very mind-boggling since I know the db and the app server are not the problem.

Am I going about this the wrong way...?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a `FirstOrDefaultAsync` available or that you can make?

Comment: That means it is waiting on `user` if I understand correctly, and `user` is assigned currently via synchronous code. Maybe there is a problem where you are mutating the same underlying `DbContext` that both the sync and async methods use? Just a dumb gues

Comment: @tacos_tacos_tacos: There is, do you feel that could make a difference? Guess I'll try it... Makes sense anyway

Comment: humor me and try it. Don't forget you need to add a check for succeeded

Comment: @tacos_tacos_tacos: Didn't make a difference, same error: `System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out`, failed on this underlying call: `var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);`

Comment: that sucks but I do think there is a possibility you may need to keep that await in there

Comment: I updated the OP with your async suggestion, theres an await there :) I pasted a full stacktrace here: http://pastebin.com/7xJbbWyn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, the answer has been found, problem was the following, for each request a transaction with level `Read Commited` was being setup. This caused the second change (create) to be blocked by the first (email confirm), causing the timeout...

```
async Task IRunBeforeEachRequest.Execute()
{
  _HttpContext.Items[IdentityContextTransactionKey] = _IdentityContext.Database.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
  _HttpContext.Items[TravellersContextTransactionKey] = _TravellersContext.Database.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
}
```

Thanks again for the help!